# Access previous object/item when using fast enumeration?

Tags: objective-c

Simple question, if your iterating through a list of objects using fast enumeration is there a quick way to refer to the previous object so you have (object and object-1)?

```
for(FuzzyThing *thisThing in allThings) {
    int thisValue = [thisThing value];
    //int prevValue = [thisThing-1 value];
}
```

If not I will use a variable to store the previous value and use that instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way to get the previous one using fast enumeration. You need to store that previous one yourself. Though in this case I will prefer to use normal loop counter unless I really really need fast enumeration for performance.

Comment: Thank you, the example is just to illustrate the point, its not actual code. Much appreciated, I have been looking but could not find anything, I was just curious.